WPF Behavior to reset IsEnabled
I want to achieve something similar to this question, i.e. I have a XAML element with IsEnabled = false, but want to specifically enable a child element. A comment in the linked SO article mentions that this was successfully done using a XAML behavior, a solution that I like a lot.
I tried implementing the behavior like this:
public class ResetIsEnabledBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        UIElement.IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata( AssociatedObject.GetType(),
            new UIPropertyMetadata( true, IsEnabledPropertyChanged, CoerceIsEnabled ) );
    }

    private static void IsEnabledPropertyChanged( DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args )
    {
    }

    private static object CoerceIsEnabled( DependencyObject source, object value )
    {
        return value;
    }
}

This works as intended first, but when the element with this behavior is used a second time, an exception occurs because the metadata for this element (a ListBoxin this case) is already registered.

System.ArgumentException: PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'ListBox'.

I know that I can use other ways than a Behavior to achieve what I want (e.g. from this post, but I ask specifically about how to implement this in a Behavior (since this offers advantages like reusability).
Now I wonder how this behavior would be correctly implemented. Any help would be highly appreciated!

It should be obvious that you can call OverrideMetadata only once per type. OnAttached is not the right place, at least not when you don't keep track of the OverrideMetadata calls you have already made.

@Clemens: Yes, this is obvious, I get why my implementation of the behavior does not work as intended. My question is: How can the behavior be implemented correctly? In the comments in the other article mentioned in the question someone mentions to have done this, and I would like to understand how (out of sheer curiosity, since I solved it differently by now).

Q: How can the behavior be implemented correctly? A: It cannot. Any attempt to do that, even successful, will introduce some issues. IsEnabled is implemented in a way that it checks the parent element for the value. It's a well known behavior, if you break it bad things may happen.
